# Why on_click is not working in Ursina Python

Tags: python

I want a new cube appears when I click on the existing cube but it appears even when I don't click.

```
from ursina import *
app = Ursina()
cube_1 = Entity(model='cube')
cube_1.on_click = Entity(model='cube', position=(1, 0, 0))
app.run()
```

**Edited:** Function works for a one cube:

```
from ursina import *
app = Ursina()
cube_1 = Entity(model='cube')
def f(position=(1, 0, 0)):
    new_cube = Entity(model='cube', position=position)
cube_1.on_click = f
app.run()
```

But how can I use it for a list of cubes? I need to exchange existing cubes to new cubes by clicking. It doesn't work well. Please help.

```
from ursina import *
app = Ursina()
cube_list = []
# Making list of cubes
for i in range(2):
    cube = Entity(model='cube', color=color.white)
    cube_list.append(cube)
# Changing existing cubes to new cubes
def f(i):
    new_cube = Entity(model='cube', position=(cube_list[i].x, 0.5, 1), color=color.red)
    cube_list[i] = new_cube
for i in range(len(cube_list)):
    cube_list[i].on_click = f(i)
app.run()
```

Comment: Right.  You are creating a new cube, then passing that cube object as the `on_click` handler.  That's not what you described.  To do what you describe, `on_click` must be a function which creates a new Entity.

Comment: @Tim Roberts edited the question